# Progressive Engagement With Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller

I am working on an app that allows any visitor to upload a media file for feedback without signup. After they've uploaded it, they are able to opt in to have email notifications (this requires a name & email). If they are visiting to see another user's post, they would be able to comment (this also requires a name & an email).

In both situations, I want the current user, who is a guest with no info in the db, to be able to carry out each action before requiring them to put in their information. I also want to carry out the task after they've successfully provided that information.

So far, I am at a loss on how to implement this functionality. My problem is mainly with the commenting portion. I should be able to type up my comment into a textarea, hit submit, be prompted to input my name & email, and then submit the comment if everything is valid.

I'm not sure what code I could show that would help answer this, but I'm willing to provide whatever necessary. This has been a huge stopping point for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the best way to go. But you could use a valid flag on such things. Create the comment in the database. Once they register/sign up, validate the saved record so it will show up on the page. Same with the images. You could then write a cron job or something to clear old invalid items if you're worried about space.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I don't have an explicit sign up area for the site, so I'd worry that the comment would get lost. I'd still have to find a way to prompt them to provide their name & email.

Comment: Write an after_filter on the said create actions. Once they do a full sign up, validate all associated records to that user.